# Showing Sufficiency of a Statistic

Tags: mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, sufficient-statistics

Suppose that $X_1, X_2, \cdot \cdot \cdot \ , X_n$ is a random sample from a continuous distribution with pdf $f_X(x;\theta) = \theta x^{\theta-1}$, for $\ 0\leq x \leq 1$. Show that $W=\prod_{i=1}^n X_i$ is a sufficient statistic for $\theta.$ Is the maximum likelihood estimator for $\theta$ a function of $W$?

Here's what I did:

$$P(X_1=x_1,...,X_n=x_n|W=w)=\cfrac{P(X_1=x_1,...,X_n=x_n,\prod_{i=1}^nX_i=\prod_{i=1}^nx_i)}{P(\prod_{i=1}^nX_i=\prod_{i=1}^nx_i)} \stackrel{redundancy}= \cfrac{P(X_1=x_1,...,X_n=x_n)}{P(\prod_{i=1}^nX_i=\prod_{i=1}^nx_i)}=\cfrac{\theta^n(\prod_{i=1}^nx_i)^{\theta-1}}{P(\prod_{i=1}^nX_i=\prod_{i=1}^nx_i)}$$

Here I am stuck. I am having difficulty breaking up the probability in the denominator. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your distribution is $\mathsf{Beta}(\theta, 1).$ [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Statistical_Inference) has a very long article on beta distributions (showing lots of pretty pictures, at least), with a discussion on MLEs (hence sufficiency) more than halfway down. Possibly useful.

Comment: The analysis of $\log(W)$ is much easier.

Comment: This question and its answers can be found in multiple posts on this site. But you cannot work with probabilities here (it is a continuous distribution). Do you know Factorization theorem?

Comment: @StubbornAtom Factorization thm has not yet been covered in my class

Comment: @StubbornAtom I can't find the question as another post, can you please link it?

Comment: Sufficiency is mentioned [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/253211/119261) and MLE is mentioned [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/133843/119261) for example. These do not discuss your exact questions of course but they contain the answers which you would have to work out on your own. You might want to add the `self-study` tag to your question and read the tag wiki.

Comment: @Xi'an heck yeah it does